# How interact with controllers by tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have many different controllers on my view, I have some pickerview creating by code like:

```
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 243, 320, 216)];
switch (sender.tag){
    case 0:
        picker.tag = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        picker.tag = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        picker.tag = 2;
        break;
    case 3:
        picker.tag = 3;
        break;
}

picker.delegate=self;
picker.dataSource = self;
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

Now I need to use default setting for it (`viewdidload`). How can I do it by using tag?

Comment: you should consider not using tags at all. instead assign the possible sender to some ivars/properties and compare those with the sender that triggered the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIPickerView *picker = [self.view viewWithTag:X];
[picker adjustIt];
```

Comment: One problem here could be that there are probably many views with tag 0 besides the picker view.

Comment: Right u r. I'd advice not to use 0,1,2 at all. The better way to make an enum with tags.

Comment: better: not use tags at all and compare sender with ivars/properties